# Redirect to custom URL after login

Tags: content-management

I have integrated `Federated Authentication`.

After user is authenticated, I want to redirect to another page instead of dashboard page.

So, on which pipeline can I write that logic where I can get `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticate` true before redirecting to dashboard page?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Sitecore documents you must create a new processor for the `owin.identityProviders` pipeline. To create a new processor:

1. Inherit the `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.IdentityProviders.IdentityProvidersProcessor` class.
2. Override the `IdentityProviderName` property with the name you specified for the identityProvider in the configuration.
3. Override the `ProcessCore` method.

Ref: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-federated-authentication.html

And in the `ProcessCode` method, you can add the parameters something like this.

```
public class AzureADIdentityProviderProcessor : IdentityProvidersProcessor
{
   public AzureADIdentityProviderProcessor(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, ICookieManager cookieManager, BaseSettings settings) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration, cookieManager, settings)
   {
   }

  protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
   {
       Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, nameof(args));

       var identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
       var authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();
       var saveSigninToken = identityProvider.TriggerExternalSignOut;

       var targetHostName = GetTargetHostName();
       string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/";
       string tenant = Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.Tenant");
       string clientId = Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.ClientId");
       string clientSecret = Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.ClientSecret");
       string postLogoutRedirectURI = $"{targetHostName}{Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.PostLogoutRedirectURI")}";
       string redirectURI = $"{targetHostName}{Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.RedirectURI")}";
       string scope = Settings.GetSetting("Foundation.Accounts.SSO.AD.Scope");
```

And add the pipeline here.

```
<pipelines>
   <owin.identityProviders>
     <processor type="Foundation.Accounts.Services.AzureActiveDirectory.AzureADIdentityProviderProcessor, Foundation.Accounts" resolve="true" />
   </owin.identityProviders>
 </pipelines>
```

Under this method you can add the provider for `RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync` like this.

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync,
                SecurityTokenValidated = this.SecurityTokenValidatedAsync
            },
```

And add the method like below.

```
private Task RedirectToIdentityProviderAsync(
        RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions>
            notification)
{
   // logic
}
```

Refer to these documents for the whole implementation.

https://rmcdigital.com/sitecore/sitecore-single-sign-on-federated-authentication-with-azure-ad/

https://www.jeroenbreuer.nl/blog/custom-identity-provider-in-sitecore/

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: If I will redirect directly from IdentityProvider then Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticate will not be true

Comment: Updated my answer. refer to the articles I have shared.

Comment: RedirectToIdentityProvider calls at the time of Authentication/Logout/Token not after,where I can access IsAuthenticate

Comment: @Bhawana Did you check the second article I have given where they are checking the authentication in this condition? `protocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication`

Comment: Yes I checked in OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication, it will give IsAuthenticated as true in second time, not the first time. I just want to know the pipeline where Sitecore set Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated as true

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 pipelines you can try out to patch your custom processor.

1. **loggedin**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <processors>
            <loggedin>
                <processor patch:before="processor[position()=last()]" method="Process"  mode="on" type="YourCustomProcessor, YourAssembly" resolve="true"/>
            </loggedin>
        </processors>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

2. **owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn** - If you are using an identity server for federated authentication this pipeline should work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <pipelines>
      <owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
        <processor  patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Pipelines.CookieAuthentication.SignedIn.CreateTicket, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication']"
            type="YourCustomProcessor, YourAssembly" resolve="true"/>
      </owin.cookieAuthentication.signedIn>
    </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Hope it helps!